# Filter for serial ports

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have an application in which I have to use the serial ports, so alright, it finds all right, but I thought and if the client has more than 1 COM port connected on the PC? How do I do when I checkbox and dial, when updating only my device appears? (My USB converter is no longer generic, it contains your own name and address).

Here is the function where I update the COM ports

```
public void AtualizarPortas()
    {
        PortasDisponiveis.Clear();
        var portas = SerialPort.GetPortNames().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        foreach (var porta in portas)
            {
                PortasDisponiveis.Add(porta);
            }
        PortaSelecionada = PortasDisponiveis.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

What could I do to get only my device to appear?

Comment: Do you know what your device's COM port will be called? If not then allow the user to select the correct device, store that choice and default to that value each time.

Comment: Unfortunately, your explanation is very hard to understand. When looking at your code example, it seems you are a speaker of Portuguese. If so, it might perhaps be easier for you to go to to the Portuguese language StackOverflow site http://pt.stackoverflow.com and post your question there in Portuguese